# `pandas iterrows` retaining unsaved changed (how?): replacing blank string value row problem

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I recently needed to fill blank string values within a `pandas` dataframe with an adjacent column for the same row.

I attempted `df.apply(lambda x: x['A'].replace(...)` as well attempted `np.where`. Neither worked. There were anomalies with the assignment of "blank string values", I couldn't pick them up via `''` or `df['A'].replace(r'^\s$',df['B'],regex=True)`, or replacing `df['B']` with e.g. `-`. The only two things that worked was `.isnull()` and `iterrows` where they appeared as `nan`.

So `iterrows` worked, but I'm not saving the changes.

How is `pandas` saving the changes?

```
mylist = {'A':['fe','fi', 'fo', ''], 'B':['fe1,','fi2', 'fi3', 'thum']}
coffee = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

print ("output1\n",coffee.head())

for index,row in coffee.iterrows():
    if str(row['A']) == '':
        row['A'] = row['B']   
 
print ("output2\n", coffee.head())
```

---

```
output1
     A     B
0  fe  fe1,
1  fi   fi2
2  fo   fi3
3      thum

output2
       A     B
0    fe  fe1,
1    fi   fi2
2    fo   fi3
3  thum  thum
```

---

**Note** The dataframe is an object BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), the documentation says :

> **You should never modify something you are iterating over.** This is not
> guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
> iterator returns a copy and not **a view**, and writing to it will have no
> effect.

In your case, you can use one of these *solutions (*that should work with your real dataset as well*):

```
coffee.loc[coffee["A"].eq(""), "A"] = coffee["B"]
```

Or :

```
coffee["A"] = coffee["B"].where(coffee["A"].eq(""), coffee["A"])
```

Or :

```
coffee["A"] = coffee["A"].replace("", None).fillna(coffee["B"])
```

*Still a strange behaviour though that your original dataframe got updated within the loop without any re-assign. Also, not to mention that the row/Series is supposed to return a copy and not a view..*

Comment: Thank you. I am extremely impressed by this response, one of the best. The final code worked, `.eq("")` solutions, didn't dunno why. 100% agreed `iterrows` is last resort and my code didn't look safe (very polite to point to the docs, but I think we all knew) also `iterrows` is very slow.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped ;). Yeah, vectorial code is much faster than `df.iterrows` and loops (most of the time).